# How to unblock an outgoing port in Windows (Windows 10 Pro)

Tags: windows, ssh, windows-defender

It appears that Outgoing Port 22 is blocked in a windows machine that I'm working with.

The reason I think this is that I cannot SSH into anything using the windows terminal or Putty. I tried a few of my servers and then I tried a public one. They all worked from my own windows machine (located in the USA) and not from this other machine (located in Honduras). Another guy who works for me who is based in The Philippines also does not have this problem.

I also tried connecting the machine through wifi and through a cell phone internet connection to check if the ISP itself was blocking port 22. Neither way worked so unless the cell phone company and the ISP are both blocking outgoing port 22 for some reason, the problem I am having is on the local machine.

What steps can I take to locate where this port is being blocked? I did try to load windows defender and disable it. I'm not very familiar with windows defender but I did disable "Domain Profile", "Private Profile" and "Public Profile". If there is anything else I need to do to disable it, I don't know what that is and I did not disable it.

Is there something else that I need to do in order to disable windows defender? Perhaps restart the computer after disabling?

Where else within in the system could outgoing port 22 be blocked?

Comment: Have you allowed the application within Windows Firewall? Ports are not typically blocked or allowed until an application exists on that port. If you are not an Administrator on this machine this obviously cannot be solved

Comment: [Start Windows 10 in Safe Mode with Networking](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/how-to-start-windows-10-in-safe-mode-with-networking/) to see if some installed third-party utility is blocking the port.

Answer (score 0):

Launch Windows Firewall with Advanced Security (start > run > wf.msc) and see that it's set to "Outbound connections that do not match a rule are allowed", or else add an Outbound Rule allowing Putty.

[Windows Firewall with Advanced Security](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HU6yA.png)